# C++ library - Using Quadprog++ and Array.hh

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, quadprog

I'm trying to use the Quadprog++ library (http://quadprog.sourceforge.net/) but there is no documentation about it. In particular I'm trying to do the exponential of a matrix with the function of Array.hh (http://bit.ly/Za0k1J) but I have no idea how to write it. I thought to write in this way:

```
Matrix<double> A;
A.resize(4,4);
A=A^2;
```

But it doesn't work.
Thanks a lot for the help!